# Check data from Database against Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the problem that my database can contain invalid values that come from a previous version of the software. For these values we have to decide individually how to handle them.

I have created a corresponding Entity Framework that can be used to access the database. Internally on the test systems everything worked as well, but during the first test installation on a customer system the program always crashed due to the invalid values in the database.

Now the question is can I detect the errors in the database using the Entity Framework?

I would like to know in which records, which columns lead to errors.

I can't assume any Keys to get each Entity on its own. So my first idea was to check each repository (`DbSet`) from the `DbContext` for each entity (`QueryingEnumerable`). However, with `DbSet` you can't really access a single entity, you can only go through the query until the first error occurs.

Also, I still don't know which columns led to the error since the exceptions don't contain any information.

Any suggestions what else I can try?

Comment: please include the displayed error message, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have ids or keys for given entities held by dbSet, then you can get single entity.

```
// In repository or somewhere else, where you have access to this particular DbSet
DbSetOfSomeEntity.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == /* Some id number, guid etc */)
```

Access them in `try-catch` block, read exception and decide what to do next.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any information about the entity data either. To query all entities individually via the primary key is impossible.

Comment: Then try `DbSetOfSomeEntity.OrderBy(p=>p.Id).Skip(0).Take(1)` and iterate through skip amount - this will give you entities in some fixed order one at a time - assuming, that since you use EF then you have entity class with known fields, since you want to use dbSet.